# Delegate Methods is not getting Called

Tags: ios, objective-c, media

My App fetches all the photos of Facebook and Instagram and display it on the HDMI TV.I have created receiver app ID on the Google cast developer console.but i am not sure how to use 'Google Cast receiver manager' in our application and i have also added google cast receiver SDK like that "//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js" but my TV screen display only blank and my app is not loaded.Why my app first screen not loaded.Any one have Experience in Google Cast SDK please share your experience.I am beginner in Google cast SDK and i have searched all google cast developer sides but i have not got any solution.Thanks in Advance   https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOfdO.png

Please click on the Above link it comes error when click the cast button.I have checked the logic  and found that delegate method is not called. Why this delegate method not called.I am not getting Please any one experience in google cast sdk please share your experience thanks.

Comment: - (void)deviceManagerDidConnect:(GCKDeviceManager *)deviceManager {
    NSLog(@"connected to %@!", _selectedDevice.friendlyName);
    
    [self updateButtonStates];
    [_deviceManager launchApplication:kReceiverAppID];
}

Comment: - (void)deviceManager:(GCKDeviceManager *)deviceManager
didConnectToCastApplication:(GCKApplicationMetadata *)applicationMetadata
            sessionID:(NSString *)sessionID
  launchedApplication:(BOOL)launchedApplication {
    
    NSLog(@"application has launched");
    self.mediaControlChannel = [[GCKMediaControlChannel alloc] init];
    self.mediaControlChannel.delegate = self;
    [_deviceManager addChannel:self.mediaControlChannel];
}

Comment: i don't know how to create a .html file for loading the app.

Comment: I have share a link of my first screen of the app.Please help me.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Add your code into question description not in comments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841273/how-to-properly-connect-to-google-cast-device-and-cast-an-url-with-an-custom-rec

this may help you

Comment: It is a timeout problem, try searching for increasing timeout interval or reconnection when session times out

Comment: thanks, i am trying!!!